# Making quick bot to warn people

Tags: email, txt

(Never mind I contacted the game devs and provided them with the info)

Earlier this morning I found a text file in a discord with literally THOUSANDS of peoples logins to a game. I have no clue if any of these work but I feel like it's only right to try to warn them.

I've spent the last 20-30 minutes copy pasting emails to these linked accounts warning them to change their password as soon as possible. Is there a way to write a script or something to pull the email from the txt and then send a pre made message to it one by one by one. I have almost no experience with coding or programming of any kind.

Comment: Don't. Inform the game company and let them deal with it. You could yourself be open to criminal charges.

Comment: Ok that's probably smart.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of format is the text file?

Extracting the list of emails from the file is your first step.

It might be easier to just get a csv of the emails and paste the whole thing into an email 'To:' box. Definitely send with BCC for security.

[I checked with 10k emails in gmail, it just took a few min to load.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xl8b.png)

If that route doesn't work for you, you can use SMTP with your email provider to send the emails.

[Tutorial on how to do that.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/send-mail-gmail-account-using-python/)

Comment: Thanks but I'm just gonna send it to the game devs and let them figure it out